# Internal and External Links Test using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Want to know how to test internal and external links using webpage. I did the following code to get the links from a page.

```
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
    {

        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
    }
```

From the above code, getting displayed the link text... Please guide me...

Thanks

Comment: How do you distinguish between an internal link & an external link? What do you want to test exactly for these links?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by your question that the text is not what you're wanting to see, but instead get a list of the actual URL's.  In that case, you need to instead get the "href" attribute:

```
for (int i=0; i < links.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was google it and got the solution.... Sorry if my question is not clear... Thanks for your ansers..

List links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

```
    int internal_count=0;
    int external_count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
    {

        String str1 = links.get(i).getAttribute("href");
        boolean b = str1.startsWith("http://newtours.demoaut");

        if(b)
        {
            System.out.println("Internal Link"+str1);
            internal_count++;
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println("External Link"+str1);
            external_count++;
        }
    }
```